# How to use a Left Join with a bunch of other joins

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join two tables based on EquipWorkOrderID. Tables(EquipWorkOrder and EquipWorkOrderHrs)
With the query I have below it duplicates the row based on ID if there is two UserNm's for the Same ID. I want the two UserNm's and the Hrs if the ID match's in the same role if possible.

example of what my results give me now

```
EquipWorkOrderID/Equip/Description/Resolution/UserNm/Hrs
---------------------------------------------------------
1              / ForkLift / Bad   /Fixed/John Doe / 2
1              /Forklift / Bad    /Fixed/Jane Doe /2
```

What I would Like to see

```
EquipWorkOrderID/Equip/Description/Resolution/UserNm1/Hrs1/UserNm2/Hrs2
---------------------------------------------------------
1              / ForkLift / Bad   /Fixed/John Doe  / 2  / Jane Doe / 2
```

```
Select * From

(
    Select  
        a.EquipWorkOrderID,
        c.UserNm, 
        b.Hrs
    From
        EquipWorkOrder a
    
    Left Join EquipWorkOrderHrs b
        On a.EquipWorkOrderID = b.EquipWorkOrderID
    Left Join AppUser c
        On c.UserID = b.UserID
) t
Pivot (
        Count(Hrs)
        For UserNm  IN (
            [Tech1],
            [Tech2],
            [Tech3],
            [Tech4],
            [Tech5])
) AS pivot_table
```

Comment: How does your title question relate? You haven't used a left join... you are using old style inner joins, which should not longer be used. You should be using explicit joins.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use a left join with the old style inner joins or another way.

Comment: Turning row values (John Doe, Jane Doe) into columns (UserNm1, UserNm2) is called "pivoting" the data. Syntax and examples can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).

Comment: @sander I looked at the documentation, but I am still not sure how to add it to my current  query.

Comment: Added a possible answer, definitely have a look a the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abd3bac2b4a299435c520a43eb2bdcdd) for understanding how the thing works.

Comment: "I looked at the documentation, but I am still not sure how to add it to my current query"  Have you even tried it?  If you only look at the documentation, nothing will get done.

Answer (score 1):

I have placed the result of your query in a table (`selection`) and retrieved the data from it in a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (`cte`). Replace the content of the CTE with your query and add the two new columns I created (`UsrNum` and `HrsNum`).

My solution uses a double [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) (one for the `UserNm` column and one for the `Hrs` column) followed by a grouping. This may not be ideal, but it gets the job done.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abd3bac2b4a299435c520a43eb2bdcdd) to show how I built up the solution.

**Sample data**

This just recreates the results of your current query.

```
create table selection
(
  EquipWorkOrderID int,
  Equip nvarchar(10),
  Description nvarchar(10),
  Resolution nvarchar(10),
  UserNm nvarchar(10),
  Hrs int
);

insert into selection (EquipWorkOrderID,Equip,Description,Resolution,UserNm,Hrs) values
(1, 'ForkLift', 'Bad', 'Fixed', 'John Doe', 2),
(1, 'Forklift', 'Bad', 'Fixed', 'Jane Doe', 2);
```

**Solution**

Replace the first part of the CTE with your query and add the two new columns.

```
with cte as
(
  select EquipWorkOrderID,Equip,Description,Resolution,UserNm,Hrs,
   'Usr' + convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over(partition by Equip order by UserNm)) as 'UsrNum',
   'Hrs' + convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over(partition by Equip order by UserNm)) as 'HrsNum'
  from selection
)
select ph.EquipWorkOrderId, ph.Equip, ph.Description, ph.Resolution,
       max(ph.Usr1) as 'UserNm1',
       max(ph.Hrs1) as 'Hrs1',
       max(ph.Usr2) as 'UserNm2',
       max(ph.Hrs2) as 'Hrs2'
from cte c
pivot (max(c.UserNm) for c.UsrNum in ([Usr1], [Usr2])) pu
pivot (max(pu.Hrs) for pu.HrsNum in ([Hrs1], [Hrs2])) ph
group by ph.EquipWorkOrderId, ph.Equip, ph.Description, ph.Resolution;
```

**Result**

Outcome looks like this. `Jane Doe` is `UserNm1` because that is how the new `UserNum` column was constructed (`order by UserNm`). Adjust the `order by` if you need `John Doe` to remain first.

```
EquipWorkOrderId  Equip     Description  Resolution  UserNm1   Hrs1  UserNm2  Hrs2
----------------- --------- ------------ ----------- --------- ----- -------- -----
1                 ForkLift  Bad          Fixed       Jane Doe  2     John Doe 2
```

---

*Edit*: solution merged with original query (untested)

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT TOP 1000
        --Start original selection field list
        ewo.EquipWorkOrderID,
        ewo.DateTm,
        equ.Equip,
        equ.AccountCode,
        equ.Descr,
        ewo.Description,
        ewo.Resolution,
        sta.Status,
        au.UserNm,
        ewoh.Hrs,
        cat.Category,
        ml.MaintLoc,
        equt.EquipType,
        cre.Crew,
        ewo.MeterReading,
        typ.Type,
        --Added two new fields
        'Usr' + convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over(partition by Equip order by UserNm)) as 'UsrNum',
        'Hrs' + convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over(partition by Equip order by UserNm)) as 'HrsNum'
    FROM EquipWorkOrder ewo
    JOIN EquipWorkOrderHrs ewoh
        ON ewo.EquipWorkOrderID = ewoh.EquipWorkOrderID
    JOIN AppUser au
        ON au.UserID = ewoh.UserID
    JOIN Category cat
        ON cat.CategoryID = ewo.CategoryID
    JOIN Crew cre
        ON cre.CrewID = ewo.CrewID
    JOIN Equipment equ
        ON equ.EquipmentID = ewo.EquipmentID
    JOIN Status sta
        ON sta.StatusID = ewo.StatusID
    JOIN PlantLoc pll
        ON pll.PlantLocID = ewo.PlantLocID
    JOIN MaintLocation ml
        ON ml.MaintLocationID = ewo.MaintLocationID
    JOIN EquipType equt
        ON equt.EquipTypeID = ewo.EquipTypeID
    JOIN Type typ
        ON typ.TypeID = equ.TypeID
    ORDER BY ewo.DateTm DESC
)
select ph.EquipWorkOrderId, ph.Equip, ph.Description, ph.Resolution,
       max(ph.Usr1) as 'UserNm1',
       max(ph.Hrs1) as 'Hrs1',
       max(ph.Usr2) as 'UserNm2',
       max(ph.Hrs2) as 'Hrs2'
from cte c
pivot (max(c.UserNm) for c.UsrNum in ([Usr1], [Usr2])) pu
pivot (max(pu.Hrs) for pu.HrsNum in ([Hrs1], [Hrs2])) ph
group by ph.EquipWorkOrderId, ph.Equip, ph.Description, ph.Resolution;
```

*Edit2*: how to use pivot...

```
Select pivot_table.*
From
(
    Select  a.EquipWorkOrderID,
            b.Hrs,
            c.UserNm,
            'Tech' + convert(nvarchar(10), row_number() over(order by c.UserNm)) -- construct _generic_ names
    From EquipWorkOrder a
    Left Join EquipWorkOrderHrs b
        On a.EquipWorkOrderID = b.EquipWorkOrderID
    Left Join AppUser c
        On c.UserID = b.UserID
) t
/*
Pivot (Count(Hrs) For UserNm     IN ([Tech1], [Tech2], [Tech3], [Tech4], [Tech5])) AS pivot_table -- UserNm does not contain values like "Tech1" or "Tech2"
*/
Pivot (Count(Hrs) For GenUserNm  IN ([Tech1], [Tech2], [Tech3], [Tech4], [Tech5])) AS pivot_table -- pivot over the _generic_ names
```

Comment: trying to figure out how to add my original query. Each way I add it, It gives me a error and won't run the query.

Comment: I merged your original query with my solution. I did not test this because then I would have to recreate all the tables. I also reworked the old style joins to current style and used meaningful table aliases.

Comment: I edited my original query with the new join format. When I run your query Sander it gives me a error.

Comment: Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "Description" is "text", which is not comparable

Comment: Data type `text` appears to be [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql). Try replacing `ph.Description` with `convert(nvarchar(100), ph.Description)` in both the final `select` and the `group by`. Like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc90aa6430186885e38e66c94100197f).

Comment: Use `nvarchar(max)` if you do not want the description to be cut off after 100 characters ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47708784a62cb266bd1c0d361bcfa4a7)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220774/discussion-between-sander-and-jshaffer).

Comment: I edited my original query to a pivot query. I left some of the joins out for now. It pivots the    Hrs column but it puts 0's in each one. I also don't know the username (UserNm). It is a step the right direction.

Comment: You did not apply the `pivot` construction properly. I made a second edit to my answer to explain it (based on your revised question). For further help, please, [use the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220774/discussion-between-sander-and-jshaffer).